# Remap function key on external logitech keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I am using a Logitech K250 keyboard on my MacBook Pro.  I have already switched the <kbd>cmd</kbd> and <kbd>opt</kbd> keys in system preferences, but I would also like to remap the <kbd>function</kbd> key to <kbd>option</kbd> to make it more consistent with the default Mac keyboard. How can I do this? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do with the [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org) app.
As you have completed the installation, head to the app. In the very first tab choose the input device you wish to make a key remap for, then add a new item and define the initial key and target key (they are in the top section of the drop down).
This is it, no need to reboot. It effects immediately.

PS. it also allows you to remap the Eject key, which becomes useless if DVD drive is taken out for an extra HDD/SSD. [image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the steps you mentioned, but the remap doesn't work with the fn key; however, it works fine with other key remaps...

Comment: Hm, checked then and just now – all worked.
This is more of a general tip, but try rebooting.